# Terminal closes when executing apt-get

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apt, package-management

Each time I execute `apt-get update`, my terminal closes unexpectedly in the middle of the execution.
I think that happened because my /var/cache/apt/archives file was removed.

Is it possible to "reinstall" apt-get or reset it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-get install -f` (fix broken).

If that does not work, reinstall it with `sudo dpkg -i package_name`.

You can download apt here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/apt.